# php mail function on go daddy host server doesn't send attachment but sends on other server

Tags: php, wordpress, email, email-attachments

mail function in php on godaddy host server doesn't send attachment i've tried to add the script on another server it worked very well.
the problem starts to show up after I installed wordpress on the server so i had to create a php file in the wp-content/themes/ 
and i called it in the wordpress..
i created a folder called "uploads" beside that script to add the uploaded files into it then sends it to email.. it doesn't read it or upload the files in it..

i want to mention again that i added the same script in other host server with a folder called "uploads" in the same directory and it worked very well.. 
anybody have an idea how to solve this?

> ```
>       if(isset($_FILES) && (bool) $_FILES) {
>        $AllowedExtensions = ["jpeg","jpg","png", null];
>        $files = [];
>        $server_file = [];
>        foreach($_FILES as $name => $file) {
>            $file_name = $file["name"];
>            $file_temp = $file["tmp_name"];
>            foreach($file_name as $key) {
>                $path_parts = pathinfo($key);
>                $extension = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
>                if(!in_array($extension, $AllowedExtensions)) { die("Extension not allowed"); }
>                $server_file[] = "uploads/{$path_parts["basename"]}";
>            }
>            for($i = 0; $i<count($file_temp); $i++) { move_uploaded_file($file_temp[$i], $server_file[$i]); }
>        }
>        $to = "John doe <myemail@gmail.com>"; // <-- Your Valid Email goes HERE 
>        $from = "abcabc@example.com";
>        $dte= date();
>        $subject ="Work Order $dte";
>        $message = $body_msg;
>        // $message = trim(strip_tags($body_msg));
>        $headers = "From: $from";
>        $semi_rand = md5(time());
>        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
>        $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
>        $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
>        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
>       for($i = 0; $i<count($server_file); $i++) {
>            $afile = fopen($server_file[$i],"rb");
>            $data = fread($afile,filesize($server_file[$i]));
>            fclose($afile);
>            $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
>            $name = $file_name[$i];
>            $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$name\"\n" .
>                 "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " >filename=\"$name\"\n" .
>                 "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
>           $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
>       }
>
>        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
>            echo "<h2 style='text-align: center'>mail sent to $to!</h2>";
>
>        } else {
>            echo "<p>mail could not be sent!</p>";enter code here
>        }
>    }
> ```

Comment: Have you considered contacting your hosting provider directly to see if they have any restrictions in regards to emails / attachments?

Comment: actually i did but they weren't very helpful

Comment: You're not being helpful in your description of them not being helpful. Either they have restrictions in which you can't send what you are wanting to send or they don't in which the problem lies somewhere else (check your error logs).

Comment: https://uk.godaddy.com/help/adding-file-attachments-to-email-messages-2758

Comment: https://uk.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Email/Email-attachments-not-working/td-p/70075

Comment: I think the problem is with wordpress because i called the script from another folder and it worked well

Comment: Your `else` echo statement has a syntax error.  'enter code here' is not provided as a comment.

Comment: Thanks @JustinR. but it's not the main problem i'm having here..
i think it has something to do with WordPress but i don't really know what is it.. because I've copied the script in a different folder of the WordPress theme content folder and it accessed the uploads folder successfully and worked well

Comment: I realize it's not your primary problem, but it's still important to note since it can generate another error later.  That's why it's posted as a comment, and not an answer.

Comment: I really appreciate you're trying to help .. 
i'm new to this field and don't know what to do.. 
Thank you @justin-r